# How to animate object on curve path in Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, kineticjs, curve

I would like to create a path as some curve, probably quad curve. It can be done similarly to http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/

Then I am able to create image object. However, I want to animate it along the created path (move it from start point to end point of the curve). I can use Javascript+Canvas+KineticJS(v 4.7.1). Is there any way, how to do it? I can't find any example which solves this.

Comment: I don't know the kineticJS, but I know that you can use this library to make an element follow a line:

http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nnU89/

[image]

You can calculate points along a quadratic curve with this formula:

```
// Calc an XY along a quadratic curve at interval T
// T==0.00 at start of curve, T==1.00 at end of curve
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

You pass in:

- the curve points (startPt, controlPt, endingPt)
- the interval along the curve at which to calculate XY (T)
- Note: T==0 at the start of the curve and T==1.00 at the end of the curve

Then you can create a Kinetic.Animation that animates along the curve:

```
var animation = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {

    // calc an XY along the curve at interval T

    var pos=getQuadraticBezierXYatT(qStart,qControl,qEnd,T/100);

    // set some Kinetic object to that position

    yourObject.setPosition(pos);    

    // change T for the next animation frame

    T+=TDirection;
    if(T<0 || T>100){ TDirection*=-1; T+=TDirection}

}, layer);
```

Comment: Thanks. Exists any source for the getQuadraticBezierXYatT function? And how can I affect speed of animation, if I have given duration of movement?

Comment: `getQuadraticBezierXYatT()` uses de Casteljau's algorithm for plotting a Bezier Curve refactored with the 2 control points being identical (A Cubic Bezier curve with identical control points is a Quadratic Curve).  You can affect the speed of the movement by changing TDirection.

Comment: Thanks for algorithm name. I found out, that TDirection changes speed of the movement, but I'm not able to compute value of TDirection according to given time for whole movement.

Comment: A kinetic animation gives you a timer.  frame.time gives you the number of milliseconds the animation has been running.  You can use that time to replace TDirection with a delta based on the elapsed time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand to that. If I want to move object from point A to point B during 2 seconds, how can frame.time help me? Isn't easier some way with setInterval or something like that?

Comment: And is there any way how to integrate it into Kinetic.Tween? I have problem which I solve [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584824/how-to-create-ad-hoc-tweens-sequence-without-recursion-in-kineticjs)

Comment: Assume you want to animate from A to B over 2 seconds.  Save the animation starting time (startTime).  In the animation loop: var elapsedTime=frame.time-startTime; Since T==0 at the beginning of the curve and T==1.00 at the end of the curve, you can calculate the T for any elapsed time as T=elapsedTime/2000.  The 2000 is the number of ms you want the full animation to take.  If T>1.00 then the animation is over--so now stop or reverse the animation.

Comment: No, a Kinetic.Tween will not animate along a curve, so a Kinetic.Animation is the only solution for moving along a curve.

Comment: Just one more query. Is there a way, how to get number of percent, where the curvature point is on the total way? E.g. if startPoint==(0,0), controlPt==(0,5), endPt==(0,10), than I woudl like to get result 50%. I rotate image during movement and I would like to know rotation at this point before animation starts. Thanks.