# How to create ad-hoc tweens sequence without recursion in KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, tween

is it possible to create tweens sequence in KineticJS according to data saved in array without recursion?

This is my current solution including recursion:

```
function tweenFunc( image )
{
  setGlobalCoordinates();
  tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: image, 
    duration: 1,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    rotation: rot,
    onFinish: function(){
      if ( counter++ < arr.length )
      {
        tweenFunc( image );
      }
    }
  });
  tween.play();
}
```

I would like to have solution which creates tweens before first animation and following tweens start from final position of predecessor.
This project includes animation of 4 images in the same time for many position sequence.

Comment: I see you're not using easing.  How about using an animation instead of tweening--seems more appropriate for sequences that need multiple waypoints.

Comment: And is possible to set waypoint and time of duration between 2 waypoints for animation? I wasn't able to find it. I'm using default linear easing, so I omit it from code. And other problem can be necessity of changing object offset.

Comment: Why you don't want to use recursion?

Comment: @lavrton: A semi-related question :-)  -- I haven't looked at KineticJS code lately.  I know .Tween uses an animation.  Is a new animation spawned for each .Tween (4 concurrent tweens==4 animations) or do the animations get batched somewhere "under the hood" (4 concurrent tweens==1 animation)?

Comment: I need to animate 4 images at one moment and each image has its own trajectory, which is computed from distance and direction of movement according to current position(not to initial position). Recursion usage leads to situation, when images don't move in the same time and in case of a lot of data usage, problem with stack can appear.

Comment: And I need to set duration of each movement between 2 positions, so I don't know, whether it's possible to create with Animation in any way, or I need to use Tween?